# Vue.js: how to access injected value in computed method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I used provide/inject mechanism to pass data from parent to grand-children, but in one of my components I need to handle the data before sending it to the template.

So I have:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MrComponent',
  inject: ["mydata"],
  computed: {
    processedData() {
      const mydata = this.mydata;
      return mydata + 1; // Some handling of the data here
    }
  }
})
```

But I get the following error:

```
[vue-cli-service] TS2339: Property 'mydata' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: never) => any) | undefined; }, { chartOptions: { responsive: boolean; maintainAspectRatio: boolean; cutout: string; borderWidth: number; }; }, ... 15 more ..., {}>'.
[vue-cli-service]   Property 'mydata' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: never) => any) | undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHan...'.
[vue-cli-service]     41 |   computed: {
[vue-cli-service]     42 |     chartData() {
[vue-cli-service]   > 43 |       const mydata = this.mydata;
[vue-cli-service]        |                           ^^^^^^^^
[vue-cli-service]     44 |     }
[vue-cli-service]     45 |   }
[vue-cli-service]     46 | })
```

If I access `mydata` in the template, it works:

```html
<template>
{{ mydata }}
</template>
```

But I need to do some other operatios with mydata before displaying it. What is the right way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just checked in online editor and works fine for me, you must have an error somewhere. How do you use `processedData`?

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/helen-fornazier/app-flc-22/blob/master/src/components/MrProgress.vue#L41
I inject a variable called `fastdata` and I try to compute it under computed, returning `chartData` that I use in the template. I simplified the example, `mydata` is the `fastdata` and `processedData` is the `chartData`.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2775#issuecomment-749049911

Comment: you mean the annotation? I just tried `chartData(): any {` and I get the same thing

Comment: My issue was on the typescript, I wrote `export default defineComponent< {fastdata: any}>({` and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a Vue bug to me, as the prop should be detected automatically from the `inject` option (filed [`vuejs/core#5931`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5931)), but there are a couple workarounds...

### Option 1: Fake prop type in `defineComponent`

If your component has no `props`, you could "fake" a `mydata` prop by specifying it in the first type argument of `defineComponent()`:

```js
export default defineComponent<{ mydata: number }>({
  inject: ['mydata'],
  computed: {
    processedData() {
      // `this.mydata` is number
    }
  }
})
```

However, this workaround is fragile as it breaks the types as soon as you add the `props` option.

### Option 2: Use Composition API

Switch the relevant parts of the code to the Composition API (i.e., [`inject()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#inject) and [`computed()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed)):

```js
import { defineComponent, inject, computed } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const mydata = inject('mydata') as number
    const processedData = computed(() => {
      return mydata + 1
    })

    return {
      processedData
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! My error was in not declaring the type of `mydata`, I added it like your example and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Glad that workaround helped. I recommend keeping an eye on the linked GitHub issue, as I'm pretty sure this is a bug. `mydata` should've been automatically detected as a component prop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Utility Types - ComponentCustomProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#componentcustomproperties)?

```js
declare module 'vue' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
    fastdata: {
      user: {
        nome: string,
        tel: string,
        pts: number,
        nivel: number,
        proximo_nivel: number,
        tot_kg: number,
        coleta: Array<any>,
      },
      noticias: Array<any>,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: This declares the type globally though, so every component would get these properties, not just the component that is injecting the type.

Comment: As it should be, you can inject anywhere.

Comment: @user16695029 But the prop should only be availble to components that *actually* inject it.